# How to add OCX file in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a `winform` project that besion of OCX file.
The first time I managed to add this file in Visual 2013 but when I created a setup project, there was this message

[image: ImageErreur01]

I tried to fix it with regsvr32. but there was this message

[image: ImageErreur02]

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

VS -> tools -> choose toolbox items...

[image]

select com components and browse the ocx:

[image]

Now, the ocx will appear in the toolbox, drag it to your form and use it as a component.